# Same Apple ID for distributing own apps and others

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode9

I have an Apple ID that I used to distribute apps. Recently I am using the same Apple ID with developer role for another company. While I can build and sign apps, I am unable to upload the binary using XCode 9. The reason it says is "No Accounts with iTunes Connect access has been found for company XYZ". The company says it has added me as a user in iTunes Connect but when I login to iTunes Connect, I don't find an option to switch between personal & company portfolio. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get email and accept invitation to itunes connect, otherwise you will not have access

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `iTunes Connect` and `Developer Portal` these two are totally different. With one email you can only check your own apps and data in `iTunes Connect` but can have multiple memberships in `Developer Portal`. Go to https://developer.apple.com and log in with your Apple ID and on the top you can tap your name drop down will appear with all memberships for that account.

If you want to access their `iTunes Connect` then you have to ask them to go to `Users and Roles` and add your email that **is not** your current Apple ID. Then you will be able to connect to their `iTunes Connect` with the new Apple ID.

More info:

https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/

http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/04/01/itunes-connect-multiple-accounts.html